# How to get values as an array from 2 select box in Jquery?

Tags: jquery

I am new to jquery and am trying to get values in an array from 2 different select option box in jquery and with this array I want to filtering the object array.

This is the select option box and both has a same id "attribute"

```
<div class="variant">
<select name="d001" id="attribute">
  <option value="black">Black</option>
  <option value="pink">Pink</option>
  <option value="white">White</option>
</select>

<select name="d002" id="attribute">
  <option value="7">7</option>
  <option value="8">8</option>
  <option value="9">9</option>
</select>
</div>
```

I run with onChange function and could get single value and target name

````
        $(document).on('change','.variant select',function(a){
            a.preventDefault();
            var select = $(this).val();
            var attribut = a.target.name;
            
           //Here I tried to get all selected value from both select box but only able to get value from first select box and secound one return empty
　　　　　　　let selectedVal = $("option:selected").val();
           console.log(selectedVal);
            
        }) ```
````

Comment: Please note that you can't have multiple elements with the same id, ID should always be unique

Comment: Maybe something like `let selectedVal = $(".variant select").map(function() {return $(this).val()}).get();`

Comment: It works! Thank you.
Can I use this data to filter object array?